# problem with multiple xfbml facebook like buttons for urls with hash tag

Tags: facebook, url, hash, facebook-like, xfbml

I am very confused about the way the xfbml like button actually works with urls.

I had multiple xfbml facebook like buttons working perfectly fine for a couple of month on a ajax site with url with hash tag.

For example: `http://example.com/#/section1/subsection1/`

Very recently this stopped working and all the like buttons now only display to total amount of likes given to the root url (example.com).

I did some research and built a little testpage for this matter:
http://luckyarts.de/liketest.html

Please check my testpage to fully understand what the issue is.
The URL Linter from Facebook also didn´t really get me any further.

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated as i am puzzled. Thanks!!

**Update:** I deactivated the test page... please do not follow the link. I concluded that facebook does not scrape urls of ajax websites that have an url with hashtag..so the like buttons won't work properly. At least i couldn't get it to work. Please correct me if anyone finds out otherwise. For non-ajax pages the multiple instances of a XFBML like button works fine though.. as seen here: http://www.onebe.at/de/kuenstler/

Answer (score 0):

It might or might not be your answer but would it be because of the Open Graph properties? I noticed this in "http://luckyarts.de/liketest.html":

> ```
> <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.luckyarts.de"/>
> ```

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this. As written in the left column there´s a post where this is described: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=251799 . It didn´t work for me though... I tried referencing all urls via Open Graph properties and that made no difference with urls with hashtag. Additionally the URL Linter from Facebook showed errors if that was the case. 

Any clue how to do this properly?

Comment: Oh, yes. I understand what you mean now. Sorry.

Comment: My feeling is that in the Open Graph, you need separate meta properties for separate objects. I mean that you might not really be able to specify a bunch of OG properties for more than one object on the same page. What I did in my application is that have these pages available to Facebook servers but when a browser hits them, it is redirected to the another one (in your case, something like "http://....#anchor_xyz"). Facebook servers have a user-agent header containing "facebookexternalhit".
On the other hand I never thought of declaring several OG objects in the one page. Maybe there's a way.